# How to find matches that occur within a specified string with regex?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a unique situation where I need to query a mongo database to find the names of people who occur in a body of text.  The query must specify the body of text and find records with values that occur in the body of text.  How can I do this with a regular expression?

I need to write a query where this would match:

`/Jonathan is a handsome guy/.test('Jonathan')`

The problem is that the text inside "test" is the value of a mongo field, so this query must be written such that the body of text is provided as input, and it matches on names that occur within (are substrings of) the body of text.

A more concrete example:

`db.test.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547e9b79f2b519cd1657b21e"), "name" : "Jonathan" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547e9b88f2b519cd1657b21f"), "name" : "Sandy" }
db.test.find({name: { $in: [/Jonathan has the best queries/]} } );`

I need to construct a query that would return "Jonathan" when provided the input "Jonathan has the best queries"

Comment: `^(?=.*\bJonathan\b).*$` if mongodb supports lookeahead.

Comment: and why cant you do `/Jonathan/.test('Jonathan is a handsome guy');`

Comment: Because I need to find records with the value "Jonathan", where "Jonathan" appears in a string I specify.  (IE, I am not trying to find values that contain a certain string, I am trying to find values /contained by/ a certain string.)

Comment: You're working backwards from the normal way: you are providing text and want to find matching regexps. That's not how the operators work, so you can't do it straightforwardly. Given you just want to test containment, it may suffice to use a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/). In the examples above, a text search on `name` for "Johnathan has the best queries" would match `"name" : "Johnathan"`.

Answer (score 1):

This `$where` may do the trick, though can be very slow:

```
db.test.find({$where: function() {
  var mystr = '/Jonathan has the best queries/'; 
  var patt = new RegExp(this.name);
  if (patt.test(mystr)) return true;
  return false;
}})
```

Comment: Thanks, I looked at $where but I am querying over several hundred thousand documents, so need the lookup to be hella performant.  Or at least not terribly slow.